# It is possbile to update Symfony 5 from 4.21.6 on Windows 7?

Tags: symfony, command, updates, windows-7-x64, symfony5

do you know if it's possible from the command ?
It's like windows 7 can't download so I want to find a way to have symfony 5,

Am I able to work on a project Symfony 5 with my friends ?

Comment: Let's ask the other way: why shouldn't that be possible? There's a clear upgrade guide provided by Symfony, and if you follow it, it should definitely be possible to run the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

symfony upgrade is independent of your operating system.
Here is the Documentation for the Upgrade: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html